# Date on y-axis of Bar Graph in PBI not reflecting what is on the graph

Tags: powerbi

The date on the y-axis shows Feb 2023, but when I hover over the 3.0M on the orange, it shows January 2023. January 2023 is correct. But why is it showing Feb 2023 on the y-axis and more importantly, how do I fix it? Thanks!

[Bar Graph screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tXz5.png)

I tried playing around with the data types of the Date Field in the Tables Tab, and changed it to mmmm-yyyy, as it was originally dd/mm/yy (the date that is inputted in the cell is the last day of each month, however I cannot change the data in the cell.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.